# Hyper-V and Running Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, hyper-v

Is there any way to leave hyper-v enabled and run a android emulator from android studio? I get the error: *cpu acceleration status: hax kernel module is not installed*, even though it was installed. Any suggestions?
Thank you in advance

Comment: I think you mean VT-x, not Hyper-V

Comment: Use the VS Android if you have it - loads better.